# Read a part of a MySQL table in spark using JDBC connector

Tags: mysql, azure, apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark

I am trying to read a table from MySQL database using a JDBC connector in pyspark. My script to read the table is :

```
query = "SELECT * FROM C WHERE hitId = 4235441"

readConfig = {
  "driver": driver,
  "url": url,
  "dbtable": tableName,
  "user": user,
  "password": password,
  "query_custom": query
}

saveLocation = mountPoint + "/" + tableName
print(saveLocation)

readDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(**readConfig).schema(tableSchema).load()
readDF.write.format("delta").option("mergeSchemas", "True").mode("overwrite").save(saveLocation)
```

I am trying to read only the particular rows which have a hitId of 4235441.

The issue is, still the whole table is being read instead of rows satisfying the custom query. **Anyone can point out what is wrong in my script, or if anyone knows any other method to achieve objective?**

I am stuck for quite a time, so any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `readConfig` near `dbtable` option your are specifying the table_name. Instead try specifying the `query` like below

```
query = "SELECT * FROM C WHERE hitId = 4235441"

readConfig = {
  "driver": driver,
  "url": url,
  "dbtable": query,
  "user": user,
  "password": password,
}
```